# How to style the content from a .txt file opened with PHP

Tags: php, css

I've got a .txt file that I open with PHP. My question is: How do I style the content in that .txt file? i.e. an other font or to display the text bigger.

PHP code:

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Now Playing</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("muziek.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("muziek.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You style it like any other text.

Comment: Also rather use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or just [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) and don't forget [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the text into an HTML document.

You style it as you would any other part of an HTML document.

Assuming the file contains plain text with no HTML special characters inside it, the obvious approach would be use the `body { /* rules */ }` selector in your stylesheet.

If you want something more nuanced, you'll need to add markup to the text. Either by hand, or programatically (and how you do it programatically would depend on the specific input and desired output).

Answer (score 0):

The php script is replaced on server with text from file. Browser gets plain `html` file. You just style it with css as any other text. For example you can surround php code with `<div class="file"></div>` and in css file style it to your liking. `.file{ color:red; }`